# How to click on the button with text as Export as per the url through Selenium and Python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am stuck and I would love your help. I am not a Python genius, so apologies for the language. I need to click on a button (Export) on this website https://www.fec.gov/data/filings/?data_type=processed&committee_id=C00097485. The button should drive to the bottom of the page where a link to an Excel file appears. Now, I have used this code:

```
text="//button[@type='button' and contains(.,'Export')]"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.fec.gov/data/filings/data_type=processed&committee_id=C00142711")
time.sleep(5)
button=driver.find_element_by_xpath(text)
button.click
```

The script runs fine, no error messages. The website appears, but the 'click' doesnt take place. 
I also tried:1) the "wait driver until element is clickable", 2) the ActionChain to move the cursor, 3) to substitute click with sendKeys. 
There is no Iframe. I tried also on Chrome. I am using a pc with Windows 10.

What am I doing wrong??? Considering that with other websites, the click function works perfectly fine!

Comment: Click is a method so it should be `button.click()`. You are missing parens. Also, it would be better if you used `WebDriverWait` instead of `.sleep()`, e.g. `button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, text)));`

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! the click() was the problem!!!

Comment: No problem. I've added my comment as an answer, if you want to accept it so that the question doesn't get left unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Click is a method so it should be `button.click()`. You are missing parens.

Also, it would be better if you used `WebDriverWait` instead of `.sleep()`, e.g. `button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, text)));`

Answer (score 0):

As per the *url* the button with text as **Export** is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so you need to induce _WebDriverWait_for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get("https://www.fec.gov/data/filings/?data_type=processed&committee_id=C00097485")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.js-export.button.button--cta.button--export"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: fec_gov]